# Can't move Div's closer to the top

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to create a block of six divs at the top of my page and just under it have a div with text in it and just under that a block of div's 3 wide. Currently, I have the 6 divs at the top in a line, the bottom block lined up, and the middle div appearing. The issue is that there is a space in between the middle div and the top div block. My HTML is:

```
<div class="page">
<a href="/menu/kale-grain-bowls"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 kale-grain-bowls">Kale & Grain Bowls</div></a>
<a href="/menu/salads"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 salads">Salads</div></a>
<a href="/menu/burgers-sandwiches"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 burgers-sandwiches">Burgers & Sandwiches</div></a>
<a href="/menu/sides"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 sides">Sides</div></a>
<a href="/menu/smoothies-shakes"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 smoothies-milkshake">Smoothies & Milkshakes</div></a>
<a href="/menu/kids-real-meals"><div class="col-m-2 col-2 kids-real-meals">Kid's Real Meals</div></a>
<div class="menu-type">Sides</div>
<div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3"><a href="sides/real-fries"><div class="real-fries">REAL FRIES</div><a>
<div class="textblock">hand-cut & finished in the oven</div></div>
<div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3"><a href="sides/sweet-potato-fries"><div class="sweet-potato-fries">SWEET POTATO FRIES</div><a>
<div class="textblock">hand-cut & finished in the oven</div></div>
<div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3"><a href="sides/crisp-veggies"><div class="crisp-veggies">CRISP VEGGIES</div><a>
<div class="textblock">broccoli, cauliflower, zucchini, carrots, kale</div></div>
<div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3"><a href="sides/side-salad"><div class="side-salad">SIDE SALAD</div><a>
<div class="textblock">choose any of our salads as a side</div></div>
<div class="foodblock col-m-3 col-3"><a href="sides/seasonal-special-grilled-zucchini"><div class="seasonal-special">SEASONAL SPECIAL: GRILLED ZUCCHINI</div><a>
<div class="textblock">parm, basil, balsamic</div></div>
</div>
```

My CSS is:

```
.page{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu-type{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}
.kale-grain-bowls{
    background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin:2.5px;
    position: relative;
}
.salads{
    background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin:2.5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 72px;
}
.burgers-sandwiches{
    background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin:2.5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 144px;
}
.sides{
    background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin:2.5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 216px;
}
.smoothies-milkshake{
    background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin:2.5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 288px;
}
.kids-real-meals{
    background-image: url('../images-source/templateFoodMainPage.png');
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin:2.5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 360px;
}
.real-fries{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.sweet-potato-fries{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.crisp-veggies{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.side-salad{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.seasonal-special{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images-source/communitybottom.png');
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I have been working at this for a few hourss and so far have gained no traction. I've been told it may be an issue with closing div's properly but I have combed through looking for errors and have found none. Could someone please help. I have included the images that are used in the CSS. These are just temporary images and not the final ones to be used. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydPQj.jpg

Comment: Where is class `foodblock` even defined?

Comment: I suggest you break this down into a simplified jsfiddle so that you can focus on learning the lower level CSS stuff:  https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/2e45a3q6/  take this as an example. (also I can't really understand the question... but this is a ransom guess). 

We'll be more able to help without all the href and image srcs and stuff. Think about how much repetition you have in your CSS.

Comment: Sorry, I'm working on cleaning up the CSS now.  Sorry, it appears I missed the CSS for foodblock. Sorry, I'm trying just to show the parts of my CSS that are relevant to this issue rather than all the CSS I have on the site. I guess I missed foodblock and textblock. I have included the missing CSS in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/raw/cWXGM1Az Sorry, I don't know how I missed it.

Comment: Post your full HTML and full CSS. I think you just need to learn the basics a little better. Post everything including what your using to make your columns because we can't see what they look like properly. What you describe in your answer is not what I see when I paste your code.

Comment: I have cleaned up my CSS but now one of my divs no longer displays properly on a different page despite it all being connected the same. Now my div's that are marked float: left; float right and some no longer are inline anymore despite no actual functionality change